# Show lines that differ between pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one with the current estimate and one with the previous estimate. I want to create a new dataframe that shows the lines that have differences. Both have about 600 lines. This code:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_current_est, df_previous_est, how='outer', indicator=True)
changed_df = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] != 'both'].copy()
changed_df.drop('_merge', axis=1, inplace=True)
changed_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

changed_df = changed_df.sort_values(by='BNCropEstimateID', ascending=True)

print(changed_df)
```

produces the right result.

```
         EstimateID  Season   RPIN GrowMethodCode Variety_code  Packout_pc  QtyBins
0             10061    2023  R1000             FO          002        0.60      320
2             10061    2023  R1000             FO          002        0.60     9000
1             10062    2023  R2000             FO          068        0.76     1000
3             10062    2023  R2000             FO          068        0.76    90000
```

The line at Index 0 is from the dataframe `df_current_est` and the line at Index 2 is from `df_previous_est`. Similarly, Index 1 is from `df_current_est` and Index 3 is from `df_previous_est`.

How can I add to the code to create a new column in `changed_df` to indicate which of the original dataframes the line is from?

Comment: I thin that you should provide a minimal input of your two dataframes and the matching expected output for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_merge` column originating from the `indicator=True` parameter gives you this information but you dropped it.

Remove this line from your code:

```
changed_df.drop('_merge', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

##### note on the indices

Note that if you are not only interested in the origin of the row (`left_only`/`right_only`), but also in the **original row index**, you have to convert them to columns before the merge. Indeed, `_merge` does **not** conserve the indices (and the order), even for a left/right merge.

Then the simplest approach is to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'value1': [1, 2, 3]},
                   index=[101, 102, 103])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['two', 'four', 'three'], 'value2': [20, 40, 30]},
                   index=[201, 202, 203])

merged_df = (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(),
                      df2.reset_index(),
                      on='key', suffixes=('_1', '_2'),
                      how='outer', indicator=True)
               .query('_merge != "both"')
            )

print(merged_df)
```

Output:

```
   index_1   key  value1  index_2  value2      _merge
0    101.0   one     1.0      NaN     NaN   left_only
3      NaN  four     NaN    202.0    40.0  right_only
```

For the max index for which merged values are the same:

```
max_id_same = (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(),
                        df2.reset_index(),
                        on='key', suffixes=('_1', '_2'),
                        how='outer', indicator=True)
                 .query('_merge == "both"')
               )[['index_1', 'index_2']].max()
```

Output:

```
index_1    103.0
index_2    203.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanx mozway, that is what I get from using previous snippets, I didn't even see that. I was overcomplicating things by trying to look for the highest index where EstimateID is the same

Comment: @opperman.eric if you are interested in the original index/indices of the merged dataframe, then you have to `reset_index` before the merge as this operation does not maintain the indexes, even for a left merge. There was a hint on that in a now-deleted answer. Also if you want the highest indices for which values are the same you need to keep the `_merge == "both"`. I'll add an update to clarify this point.

Comment: Not necessary add, undelete.

Answer (score 1):

Convert indices to columns in both DataFrames:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_current_est.rename_axis('idx_df_current_est').reset_index(),
                     df_previous_est.rename_axis('idx_df_previous_est').reset_index(), 
                     how='outer', indicator=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
df_current_est = pd.DataFrame({'EstimateID':[1,2,3,4], 'BNCropEstimateID':[10, 20, 30,80]})
print(df_current_est)
   EstimateID  BNCropEstimateID
0           1                10
1           2                20
2           3                30
3           4                80

df_previous_est = pd.DataFrame({'EstimateID':[3,4,5,6], 'BNCropEstimateID':[30,20,10,30]})
print(df_previous_est)
   EstimateID  BNCropEstimateID
0           3                30
1           4                20
2           5                10
3           6                30
```

---

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_current_est.rename_axis('idx_df_current_est').reset_index(),
                     df_previous_est.rename_axis('idx_df_previous_est').reset_index(), 
                     how='outer', indicator=True)
print(merged_df)
   idx_df_current_est  EstimateID  BNCropEstimateID  idx_df_previous_est  \
0                 0.0           1                10                  NaN   
1                 1.0           2                20                  NaN   
2                 2.0           3                30                  0.0   
3                 3.0           4                80                  NaN   
4                 NaN           4                20                  1.0   
5                 NaN           5                10                  2.0   
6                 NaN           6                30                  3.0   

       _merge  
0   left_only  
1   left_only  
2        both  
3   left_only  
4  right_only  
5  right_only  
6  right_only
```

---

```
changed_df = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] != 'both'].copy()
changed_df.drop('_merge', axis=1, inplace=True)
changed_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

changed_df = changed_df.sort_values(by='BNCropEstimateID', ascending=True)

print(changed_df)
   idx_df_current_est  EstimateID  BNCropEstimateID  idx_df_previous_est
0                 0.0           1                10                  NaN
4                 NaN           5                10                  2.0
1                 1.0           2                20                  NaN
3                 NaN           4                20                  1.0
5                 NaN           6                30                  3.0
2                 3.0           4                80                  NaN
```